# Python 3.6 matplotlib.pyplot shows graph immediately without letting me apply other functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am trying to build a plot using matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

For example `plt.hist(df.amount, bins = 30)`

But when I hit enter in the console it generates the graph.

I want to apply `xlim`, `ylim` and `title` functions of `plt` but can't do this.

Anyone familiar with this behavior? Should I change Spyder settings?

Same behavior with Seaborn package.

Comment: So you're using the internal ipython console? Does it show the figures in the actual console? If so, try typing `%matplotlib` or `%matplotlib qt` before doing `plt.hist(df.amount, bins=30)`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yes it shows within the terminal in Spyder. Why it behave like this?
Should I use another development environment?

Comment: @FHTMitchell Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Just press `Ctrl+Enter` instead of `Enter` to create a new line instead of executing. That way you can add more code to customize your plot.

Comment: @steves OK :) done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try typing `%matplotlib` or `%matplotlib qt` before doing `plt.hist(df.amount, bins=30)`. This will switch the console out of "inline" mode.

Comment: There is an option to make this permanent:  Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics >Graphics backend.  Choose "automatic" instead of "inline".